# Snowflake : Merge into query from S3 to table throwing error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this query which is throwing `Error: invalid identifier 'SRC_COL_1' (line 3)` even when the file is having `SRC_COL_1` as a field. Am I missing something?

**Query:**

```
MERGE INTO DB.SCHEMA.TARGET_TABLE AS TARGET USING
  (SELECT SRC_COL_1,
          SRC_COL_2,
          REPLACE(SRC_COL_1 || '~' || SRC_COL_2, ' ', '') AS SRC_COL_3,
          SRC_COL_4
   FROM @MY_STAGE (FILE_FORMAT => 'MY_FILE_FORMAT', PATTERN => '.*MY_PATTERN.*\.txt')) AS SOURCE ON TARGET.SRC_COL_3 = SOURCE.SRC_COL_3 WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET TARGET.SRC_COL_4 = SOURCE.SRC_COL_4 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (SRC_COL_1,
        SRC_COL_2,
        SRC_COL_3,
        SRC_COL_4)
VALUES(SOURCE.SRC_COL_1, SOURCE.SRC_COL_2, REPLACE(SOURCE.SRC_COL_1 || '~' || SOURCE.SRC_COL_2, ' ', ''), SOURCE.SRC_COL_4);
```

**File format query:**

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT MY_FILE_FORMAT TYPE = 'CSV' FIELD_DELIMITER = '|' SKIP_HEADER = 1;
```

**My stage:**

```
CREATE STAGE MY_STAGE 
URL = 's3://my-bucket/folder/'
CREDENTIALS = ( AWS_KEY_ID='myAccessKey' AWS_SECRET_KEY='mySecretKey' );
```

Comment: I believe you need to use positional parameters when querying data in a stage. I'm guessing that SRC_COL_1/2/... are column headers in your file - you can't use these, you need SELECT $1, $2, $3... FROM @MY_STAGE... Your file format will also need to be set to skip the first row if it contains column headers